# Is there a way to yank into a register using visual mode without having to count lines?

Tags: vim

I've learned I can yank, say, 4 lines in visual mode into a register `r` like so: `V4j"r`. However, I don't want to have to count lines and just select them in visual mode and copy them into a register (because I want to cut and paste them to another file).

Can this be done?

Thanks,
Damian

Comment: I'm not sure from your Q, but if you have `set relativenumber` in your .vimrc (or just do it from the command line to have it temporarily with `:set rnu`), you wouldn't need to 'count' the number of lines to move down (using `j`), you would simply need to read that number from the left side.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `V4j` doesn't select four lines to begin with, and you are missing a `y`.

Anyway, `V4j"ry` is not to be taken as a whole. It really is a *composition* of three commands:

- `V` to enter visual-line mode,
- `4j` to move the cursor downward four times, expanding the visual selection to cover five lines,
- `"ry` to yank the text covered by the visual selection into register `r`.

In this case, `4j` could literally be any command that moves the cursor in visual mode: `/foo<CR>`, `'b`, etc.

`jjjj`, which is the exact "count-less" equivalent of `4j` is obviously also valid in this context so you could simply do:

```
Vjjjj"ry
```